# Why is my update_values not receiving the signal from starting the service?

Tags: python, user-interface, service, pyqt5, rpyc

I am creating a GUI using pyqt5 and rpyc. I have two widgets that are in two separate python files:

1. powersupply_service which essentially turns on the service for other widgets to connect to.

```
from PowerSupply_service import PowerSupplyService

from A_power_out import Ui_A_power_out


from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
import logging
from threading import Thread

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

class StartServerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    server_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, power_supply_service, ui_A_power_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.power_supply_service = power_supply_service
        self.ui_A_power_out = ui_A_power_out  # Pass the instance, not the class

    def run(self):
        self.power_supply_service.start_server()
        print("Signal emitted")
        self.server_started.emit()
        self.ui_A_power_out.server_running = True

class StopServerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, power_supply_service):
        super().__init__()
        self.power_supply_service = power_supply_service

    def run(self):
        self.power_supply_service.stop_server()

class Ui_powersupply_service_2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.power_supply_service = PowerSupplyService()
        self.ui_A_power_out = Ui_A_power_out()  # Initialize Ui_A_power_out instance as None initially

    def setupUi(self, powersupply_service_2):
        powersupply_service_2.setObjectName("powersupply_service_2")
        powersupply_service_2.resize(442, 300)
        self.Power_service_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(powersupply_service_2)
        self.Power_service_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 401, 71))
        self.Power_service_widget.setObjectName("Power_service_widget")

        self.powersupply_service = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Power_service_widget)
        self.powersupply_service.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.powersupply_service.setFont(font)
        self.powersupply_service.setObjectName("powersupply_service")

        self.power_service_conn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Power_service_widget)
        self.power_service_conn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 20, 71, 28))
        self.power_service_conn.setObjectName("power_service_conn")

        self.power_service_disconn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Power_service_widget)
        self.power_service_disconn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 91, 28))
        self.power_service_disconn.setObjectName("power_service_disconn")

        self.retranslateUi(powersupply_service_2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(powersupply_service_2)

        # Connect the "CONNECT"/"DISCONNECT" button to start/end the server
        self.power_service_conn.clicked.connect(self.start_server_thread)
        self.power_service_disconn.clicked.connect(self.stop_server_thread)

    def retranslateUi(self, powersupply_service_2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        powersupply_service_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("powersupply_service_2", "Form"))
        self.powersupply_service.setText(_translate("powersupply_service_2", "Power supply service:"))
        self.power_service_conn.setText(_translate("powersupply_service_2", "CONNECT"))
        self.power_service_disconn.setText(_translate("powersupply_service_2", "DISCONNECT"))

    def start_server_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()  # Terminate the previous thread if still running

        self.thread = StartServerThread(self.power_supply_service, self.ui_A_power_out)
        self.thread.server_started.connect(self.ui_A_power_out.update_values)
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_server_thread(self):
        if self.thread and self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()  # Terminate the previous thread if still running

        self.thread = StopServerThread(self.power_supply_service)
        self.thread.start()
```

2. A_power_out which connects to the service, finds the voltage value and updates the value displayed on the widget every 3 seconds.

```
class PowerDisplayClient:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def set_address(self, address):
        self.connection.power_service.exposed_set_address(address)
    
    def get_identity(self):
        return self.connection.power_service.exposed_get_identity()

    def get_voltage(self):
        return self.connection.power_service.exposed_get_voltage()
    
    def get_current(self):
        return self.connection.power_service.exposed_get_current()



class Ui_A_power_out(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.server_running = False


    def setupUi(self, A_power_out):
        A_power_out.setObjectName("A_power_out")
        A_power_out.resize(687, 428)
        self.A_power_out = QtWidgets.QWidget(A_power_out)
        self.A_power_out.setObjectName("A_power_out")

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)

        self.P_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.A_power_out)
        self.P_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 121, 31))
        self.P_out_label.setFont(font)
        self.P_out_label.setObjectName("P_out_label")

        self.A_I_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.A_power_out)
        self.A_I_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 121, 31))
        self.A_I_out_label.setFont(font)
        self.A_I_out_label.setObjectName("A_I_out_label")

        self.A_V_out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.A_power_out)
        self.A_V_out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 121, 31))
        self.A_V_out_label.setFont(font)
        self.A_V_out_label.setObjectName("A_V_out_label")

        self.A_V_out = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.A_power_out)  # Initialize A_V_out
        self.A_V_out.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 55, 16))
        self.A_V_out.setText("")
        self.A_V_out.setObjectName("A_V_out")
        self.A_V_out.setFont(font)

        self.retranslateUi(A_power_out)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(A_power_out)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(A_power_out)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_values)
        self.timer.start(3000)

    def update_values(self):
        print("Updating values...")  # Add this line for debugging
        if not self.server_running:
            print("Server not running, skipping update")  # Add this line for debugging
            return 
        connection = Connection()
        client = PowerDisplayClient(connection)
        address_A = 1
        client.set_address(address_A)
        client.get_identity()
        voltage = client.get_voltage()
        current = client.get_current()
        power = voltage * current
        self.A_V_out.setText(str(voltage))
        #self.A_I_out.setText(str(current))
        #self.A_P_out.setText(str(power))
```

My issue is that even when the service has been turned on and the signal that it is on is sent out, the update_values is not receiving the signal and hence is never getting out of the  if not self.server_running statement.

I have tried to debug and have narrowed down the issue to the fact that update_values is not receiving the signal that the service is on, but I am unsure how to correct this.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], specifically about the instance creation and application execution. Be also aware that editing or merging pyuic generated file is considered bad practice, and those files clearly warn against doing it, which is often a cause of issues similar to yours. See the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).